# Maven build on jenkins runs tests for both modules

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a maven project with multiple modules. 
Module A contains 100 test cases. Module B depends on module A and contains 50 test cases. 
When running my maven build on jenkins, Module B started showing 150 tests and the names of the extra 100 tests correspond to those of module A.

Noteably, module A contains a custom maven profile to exclude some tests when running "everyday" tests and the extensive test set is run at night.

I have another test configurations, in which A is tested more extensively and again module B shows up with the extra tests.

How do I stop maven from running tests again in module B?

Edit: The maven goal is `verify` respectively `verify -P !defaultTestSet`. Deleting the workspace before building did not change anything.

Edit 2: If module A is excluded via `verify -pl !A`, the tests do not occur in module B.

Comment: Do you have a Jenkinsfile? Or possibly two - is it one for each of A and B? It would help to see what maven goal is being run within jenkins.

Comment: Thanks ,Ryan, I don't have a jenkinsfile, I just configured the goals in the UI. I edited my goals in.

Comment: I assume it is running that goal against the top-level project. I wonder whether it would work for you to specify exactly which modules to run against. So `mvn verify -pl .,moduleA` and `mvn verify -pl .,moduleB -P !defaultTestSet`. Or to exclude a specific module so that when running for module B you could add the parameter `-pl !moduleA` to exclude moduleA for that command. An alternative might be to first `cd` into the directory of the module you want to run for.

Comment: That might work, but that's quite a hacky solution, I'm wondering why this occurs in the first place, I've never experienced this before when working with Maven/Jenkins.

Comment: I'll play a round and see if -pl tinkering helps anything.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue: Jenkins did not actually run the tests twice, it just showed them for the other module.

The cause was in the configuration of the `maven-surefire-plugin`. The `reportDirectory` was was set to ".../shippable/reports/" as we were switching over from shippable. Tests reports from both modules ended up in the same module. When Jenkins reported the tests for the first module, there was no issue, as only that module's tests were in there. When reporting tests for the second module, reports from both modules were in there and went into the report.